# SQL Help - inserting columns into a table based on distinct column values

Tags: mysql, database, sql-insert

Hi I'm trying to do the following and am a bit stuck for idea:

I have a set of data like this:

```
Column1(int)      Column2(int)       Column3(Varchar)

0                 1234               ABC-0
1                 1234               ABC-1
2                 1234               ABC-2
3                 1234               ABC-3
4                 1234               ABC-4

0                 6789               DEF-0
1                 6789               DEF-1
2                 6789               DEF-2
3                 6789               DEF-3
4                 6789               DEF-4
```

I would like to have the table updated so that an additional row is inserted for distinct column2 values where column one's value is set to 999 and column3's value is like shown below:

```
Column1(int)      Column2(int)       Column3(Varchar)
0                 1234               ABC-0
1                 1234               ABC-1
2                 1234               ABC-2
3                 1234               ABC-3
4                 1234               ABC-4
999               1234               ABC  ********New row******

0                 6789               DEF-0
1                 6789               DEF-1
2                 6789               DEF-2
3                 6789               DEF-3
4                 6789               DEF-4
999               6789               DEF  ********New row******
```

I'm pretty new to SQL and any help would be much appreciated,

Just to clarify this will be run automatically by a script after a new dataset is put into the database

Cheers

Comment: simply insert into table with INSERT query.....

Comment: Hi LolCoder, im aware of that but the values in the columns can change based on different data inputs so i cant do this statically - i need a dynamic insert statement that analyses the distinct Column2 values and  inserts one row per distint Column2 values like above..

Comment: Sorry, I still didn't get you....My thought is simply insert and while getting the data in above format, we can listed as above....Isn't it?

Comment: Cheers for the help LolCoder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall structure will be something like:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT DISTINCT 999, Column2, substr(Column3, 1, 3)
FROM your_table
```

However note that this is just a guidance.  Your `substr` function call may differ depending on the exact structure of your data and the database engine you're using.  E.g. on SQL Server it may be different from the one on MySQL.

Comment: @LolCoder I don't think I understand your comment.  The query will pull exactly one row for each subset of column2 and start of column3.  The OP is asking to insert one "summary" row for each such unique group, which is exactly what the code above does.

Comment: Cheers @Alecks G thats exactly what i needed!